# Can you downgrade from VS 2019 to VS 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have upgraded to VS 2019 but I am worried that if I need to go back to VS 2017 then I might not be able to downgrade my code?

I looked on google but no solution has been found.

I like to know whether it would be possible.

Comment: You don't have to. They run side-by-side

Comment: First tell me wrong with VS2019? If you really want to downgrade then uninstall VS2019 and then install VS2017! Moreover you can also keep both them as they run side by side!

Comment: "Is it possible" is almost never a meaningful question and is always immediately followed up with *did you **try**?*  If you were to *try* and were to *encounter a problem* then we may be able to help with that.  But "I am worried" is not a technical problem we can solve.

Comment: _(what's) wrong with VS2019?_ Well, for one thing the annoying caps bug the introduces inconsistent method names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to downgrade. Visual Studio 2019 and 2017 run [side by side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio-versions-side-by-side?view=vs-2019). Installing Visual Studio 2019 installs a new *application* in a different path. It doesn't upgrade VS 2017, so there's no reason to *down*grade.

I'm using VS 2017 and VS 2019 on the same machine for about 6 months now without issues.